# Drupal 7 sidebar content / blocks

Tags: drupal-7

Can someone help...

I'm looking for a module or method in Drupal 7 to allow content editors to define what goes in a sidebar for a given node. 'Show block on specific pages' is OK up to a point, but it becomes impractical when we've got 30+ pages and potentially 100+ blocks.

This sounds exactly what I'm after but obviously isn't built for 7 (unless anyone wants to convert it for me - happy to pay if price is reasonable)

http://drupal.org/project/block_assign

Suggestions / help!

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 0):

[Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) might be what you're looking for